# undefined function when function is present

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that looks like this:

```
class userAuthentication
{
    public static function Authenticate()
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['email']))
        {
            verify($someVar, getPass($_COOKIE['email']);
        }
    }

    public static function getPass($email)
    {
    }

    public static function verify()
    {
    }
}
```

At times (I can't pin-point exactly when), I get a fatal error :

```
Call to undefined function getPass()
```

The error is thrown at the line where I call the function in the above code sample. Why is this happening when the function clearly exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a static function in a class. Use `self::getPass()` or `static::getPass()` if you want to take advantage of Late Static Binding. Same goes for `verify()`.

Comment: Ah, I learn something new everyday. Thank you. `self::` fixed it. Made the change for other functions as well.

Answer (score 3):

`verify` is not a global function, but only valid in the scope of your class. You want

```
self::verify($someVar, getPass($_COOKIE['email']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the error occurs when you try to run `getPass($_COOKIE...` since you're calling it wrong. Since the function is a class method, you have to run it like this:

```
$this->getPass(...);
```

or if you're calling it statically:

```
self::getPass(...);
```

Making your code:

```
class userAuthentication
{
    public static function Authenticate()
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['email']))
        {
            self::verify($someVar, self::getPass($_COOKIE['email']);

            // Or...

            $this->verify($someVar, $this->getPass($_COOKIE['email']);
        }
    }

    public static function getPass($email)
    {
    }

    public static function verify()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a static method via `->func()`? May work, but should be fixed.

Comment: Why do you think so? I find it convenient that all functions defined in a class can be referenced by `$this`, static or not

Comment: `$this` is for accessing object properties and methods. Static are neither. I understand it works, but still consider it an error that should be fixed.

Comment: In any case, it's [documented by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) that static methods can be called on object instances, so regardless of your preference my answer is correct. They probably have their reasons for it

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling it as a static function.

From within the class use either:

```
self::getPass($email);
```

or (for late static binding):

```
static::getPass($email);
```

and from outside the class:

```
userAuthentication::getPass($email);
```

The line should probably be:

```
self::verify($someVar, self::getPass($_COOKIE['email']);
```